# How to make a country available on Twilio?

Tags: twilio

What should be done to add a new country to twilio numbers? Colombia is not available although many other Latin American countries are...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not Twilio support.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From the bottom of our page which lists which [countries in which Twilio has numbers](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/which-countries-does-twilio-have-phone-numbers-in-and-what-are-their-capabilities):

> Twilio is in the process of providing phone numbers in more countries as quickly as we can. Each country has different regulations regarding the purchase and sale of telephone numbers, so we are not able to provide a timeline on when numbers in a specific country will be available.

I will note that while you don't get the local number you are still able to send messages to and receive messages from Colombian numbers using Twilio numbers from other countries. Perhaps this could help you?

Comment: oh how can I do that? is there an international number kind of functionality?

Comment: Most numbers from other countries can send and receive internationally. Perhaps try with a US number and see what you can do.